# Multi Window App Development

Tags: android, multi-window

I want to develop an android application which has to run two other applications on the device with one app on upper half of the screen and the other in lower half of the screen. Any  clues/suggestions to start developing this ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why do you need to split into two different application?

Comment: You can't "run" other apps in your own app.

Comment: Thing is I want to run two apps at the same time by dividing the screen into two halves. How can we achieve that ?

Comment: Hey! did you resolved this ? any reference link ?

Answer (score 1):

**it's not possible multi-pane-layout two other apps.**

**if u want your app with multiple activities follow this tutorials for your references:**

it's called named as multi-pane-layouts and offical introduction about multi-pane-layouts below link:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html

and it's shows how to implement multi-pane-layouts on your project below link from android official side:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

and you can download example project from github below link:

https://github.com/faisalgeek/MultiPaneAndroidApp

Comment: I want to run two apps at the same time by dividing the screen into two halves. How can we achieve that ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, except via custom device firmware or ROM mods. In standard Android, only one app can be used at a time.

However:

- You are welcome to [support multi-window apps on some Samsung devices](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/Designing-For-The-Galaxy-Note-Creating-Multi-Window-Apps), as they have extended their firmware to support this concept
- You are welcome to have an activity's theme set up to not fill the screen, though anything else around the activity will at most be visible and will not respond to touch events
- If all of these applications are yours, combine them into one app, and then you can display elements of that app alongside other elements of that app however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a feature for your app which supports multi-window then Latest Android version N has a new cool feature called Multi-window support, you can let your app support multi-window which can be resized and scaled which is exactly your requirement. you can find the reference [link](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html) here